# Webstorm 10 very laggy

Tags: webstorm

I am on a Lenovo T440s with 8GB RAM and an i7, yet I still get an almost constant 35%+ CPU usage while doing anything in Webstorm. As I type, it lags and characters appear hundreds of ms after the keystroke.  Sometimes it will jump to 60%+ CPU usage and become completely unusable for a few seconds.  Is there a way to turn off indexing or something after the initial scan? I think it is the indexing that causes the constant computation. It is ridiculous that an i7 processor is having troubles simply typing in an IDE.  Does anyone else get this?

Comment: You better describe what kind of files you are editing. There are few tickets about slowness of v10 already -- usually it's about TypeScript files: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WEB

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: I am editing only HTML, CSS, JS files but have ascx files in my project as well. I am on Win8